# How do we know how many columns come from XML variable in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am passing XML type variable from one procedure to another procedure.

Set XML variable like this

```
Declare @XMLDOC XML

set @XMLDOC = (select 60 as RecordDetailID,            
                      '' as ItemText,            
                      '' as ItemNote,            
                      0 as DisplayOrder                        
               FOR XML RAW)
```

In some case I need send one more "Status" column to another procedure like below

```
  set @XMLDOC = (select  60 as RecordDetailID,            
                         '' as ItemText,            
                         '' as ItemNote,            
                         0 as DisplayOrder,
                         1 as Status  
                 FOR XML RAW)
```

How I would know how many columns have been sent to my the XML Type variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [nodes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) method to count XML attributes:

```
select count(1) from @XMLDOC.nodes('row/@*') as T(c);
```

Comment: thanks a lot that's useful for me. just for knowledge what is the meaning of count(1) ?

Comment: @KuldipMCA, `count(1)` is an artifact from PL/SQL. It improves performance because PL/SQL fetches all rows in memory before counting them if you use `count(*)`. T-SQL doesn't have this problem, though, so both forms are equivalent, I only used `count(1)` out of habit :) See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/9367c580-087a-4fc1-bf88-91a51a4ee018/.